# How do I properly do math with matrices for opengl transformations?

Tags: c++, opengl, math, matrix

I'm really confused how matrices work and how to use them possible. Just as a test, I am trying to make a rectangle rotate anti-clockwise while it is moving towards a corner, also the rectangle is half the size. Basically everything doesnt work expect rotation.

If you are wondering, I am not using GLM and i don't want to use GLM. I feel like I need to try myself but now im seriously stuck. Ive tried rearranging how I do the transformations, but I get random results.

Here is the code in main.cpp it is a custom game engine so here is just the relevant part

```
Matrix4 transform = Matrix4(); // the matrix
float d = 5, g = 1;
void OnUserUpdate() override { // Called once every frame
    transform.Translate(Vector3(d * DeltaTime, d * DeltaTime, 0.0f));
    transform.Rotate(Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), ToRadians(g));
    transform.Scale(Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f));

    g+=0.01;

    Shaders.SetMat4(shader, "transform", transform);
}
```

Here is the full matrix class. Vector3 is just float x, y, z. There is only a constructor.

```
template <typename Number> float ToRadians(Number deg) {
return deg * PI / 180;
}

struct Matrix4 {
private:
Matrix4& identity() {
    m[0] = m[5] = m[10] = m[15] = 1.0f;
    m[1] = m[2] = m[3] = m[4] = m[6] = m[7] = m[8] = m[9] = m[11] = m[12] = m[13] = m[14] = 0.0f;
    return* this;
}
public:
float m[16];
Matrix4() {
    identity();
}

Matrix4(const float src[16]) {
    Set(src);
}

void Set(const float src[16]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        m[i] = src[i];
    }
}

void Projection(float fov, float aspectratio, float nearpane, float farpane) {

}

void Translate(Vector3 v) {
    float x = v.x; float y = v.y; float z = v.y;
    m[0] += m[3] * x;   m[4] += m[7] * x;   m[8] += m[11] * x;   m[12] += m[15] * x;
    m[1] += m[3] * y;   m[5] += m[7] * y;   m[9] += m[11] * y;   m[13] += m[15] * y;
    m[2] += m[3] * z;   m[6] += m[7] * z;   m[10] += m[11] * z;   m[14] += m[15] * z;
}

void Rotate(Vector3 axis, float deg) {
    m[0] = cosf(deg)+axis.x*axis.x*(1-cosf(deg));
    m[1] = axis.y*axis.x*(1 - cosf(deg)) + axis.z*sinf(deg);
    m[2] = axis.z*axis.x*(1 - cosf(deg)) - axis.y*sinf(deg);
    m[4] = axis.x*axis.y*(1 - cosf(deg)) - axis.z*sinf(deg);
    m[5] = cosf(deg)+axis.y*axis.y*(1-cosf(deg));
    m[6] = axis.z*axis.y*(1 - cosf(deg)) + axis.x*sinf(deg);
    m[8] = axis.x*axis.z*(1 - cosf(deg)) + axis.y*sinf(deg);
    m[9] = axis.y*axis.z*(1 - cosf(deg)) - axis.x*sinf(deg);
    m[10] = cosf(deg) + axis.z*axis.z*(1 - cosf(deg));;
    m[15] = 1;
}

void Scale(Vector3 v) {
    float x = v.x; float y = v.y; float z = v.y;
    m[0] *= x;   m[4] *= x;   m[8] *= x;   m[12] *= x;
    m[1] *= y;   m[5] *= y;   m[9] *= y;   m[13] *= y;
    m[2] *= z;   m[6] *= z;   m[10] *= z;   m[14] *= z;
}
};
```

As I said I am trying to make a rectangle rotate anti-clockwise while it is moving towards a corner, and the rectangle is half the size. I used a few sources, but honestly I didn't fully understand everything

http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_matrix.html

https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Transformations

Comment: [Same concepts are taught here in a different way](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrices.html)

Comment: does this apply to 3d the same way?

Comment: Yes, the articles cover 3D, keep reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify things.

Create 3 methods, which initialize a scale, translation and rotation matrix:

```cpp
struct Matrix4 {

    // ...

    void SetScale( Vector3 v ) {
        identity();
        m[0] = v.x; m[5] = v.y; m[10] = v.z;
    }

    void SetTranslate( Vector3 v ) {
        identity();
        m[12] = v.x; m[13] = v.y; m[14] = v.z;
    }

    void SetRotate( Vector3 v, float rad ) {
        identity();

        float c = cosf(rad);
        float s = sinf(rad);
        float x = v.x, y = v.x, z = v.z;

        m[0] = x*x*(1.0f-c)+c;   m[1] = x*y*(1.0f-c)-z*s; m[2]  = x*z*(1.0f-c)+y*s;
        m[4] = y*x*(1.0f-c)+z*s; m[5] = y*y*(1.0f-c)+c;   m[6]  = y*z*(1.0f-c)-x*s;
        m[8] = z*x*(1.0f-c)-y*s; m[9] = z*y*(1.0f-c)+x*s; m[10] = z*z*(1.0f-c)+c;
    }

    // ...

}
```

Further create a method which multiplies a matrix to the current matrix:

```cpp
struct Matrix4 {

    // ... 

    void Multiply( const Matrix4 &b ) {
        Matrix4 a;
        a.Set( m );
        for ( int k = 0; k < 4; ++ k ) {
            for ( int j = 0; j < 4; ++ j ) {
                m[k*4+j] =
                    a.m[0*4+j] * b.m[k*4+0] +
                    a.m[1*4+j] * b.m[k*4+1] +
                    a.m[2*4+j] * b.m[k*4+2] +
                    a.m[3*4+j] * b.m[k*4+3];
            }
        }
    }

    // ...

}
```

Based on this methods, the methods which scale, translate and rotate the existing matrix can be implemented with ease:

```cpp
struct Matrix4 {

    // ... 

    void Scale(Vector3 v) {

        Matrix4 s;
        s.SetScale( v );
        Multiply( s );
    }

    void Translate(Vector3 v) {

        Matrix4 t;
        t.SetTranslate( v );
        Multiply( t );
    }

    void Rotate(Vector3 axis, float rad) {

        Matrix4 r;
        r.SetRotate( axis, rad );
        Multiply( r );
    }

    // ...

}
```

Make this run. After that you can try to do optimizations the methods, but you'll have a working base, to compare results.

---

Note, in `transform.Rotate(Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), ToRadians(g));` the angle is converted from degrees to radiant. `g+=0.01` is a very tiny step forward (in degree). Probably you should change that to `g+=1.0`, to get a noticeable change in ever frame.

---

Finally you've to initialize the the modem matrix (`transform`), by the identity matrix, before you do the transformations. Otherwise the new transformations would be done on top of the transformations of the previous frames. This would cause that the mesh rapidly scales down and the translation goes to no where:

```cpp
float g = 0, t = 0;
```

```cpp
void OnUserUpdate() override {

    transform = Matrix4();
    transform.Translate(Vector3(t, t, 0.0f));
    transform.Rotate(Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), ToRadians(g));
    transform.Scale(Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f));

    t += 0.1 * DeltaTime;
    g += 5;

    Shaders.SetMat4(shader, "transform", transform);
}
```

Comment: Seems to work better, though one more problem: It seems that last transform call overwrites everything else. So scaling overrules transform and rotation. Translate wasn't working as intended but I made some changes to make it work

 `void SetTranslate(Vector3 v) {`
  `identity();`
  `m[12] += v.x; m[13] += v.y; m[14] += v.z;`
 `}`

Comment: No, the scale function call overwrites the others. And it's actually the fact that the last function call overwrites the other. Example:

  `transform.Translate(Vector3(d * DeltaTime, d * DeltaTime, 0.0f));`
  `transform.Rotate(Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), ToRadians(g));`
  `transform.Scale(Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f));`

Because Scale() is called last, it overwrites transform and rotate, which was the problem.

Comment: your example doesn't set the value of the output to the matrix itself. Only does the calculations, so I made some edits, maybe that's the problem?

Edits:  `Matrix4 Scale(Vector3 v) {
  Matrix4 s = Matrix4(m);
  s.SetScale(v);
  Multiply(s);
  return s
 }`

Without the edits, nothing happens.

Comment: @BobTheTreeGod this are methods of the class `Matrix4` not functions! All the methods set the member `m`. `Multiply` changes the member `m`! All like your original methods `Scale`, `Translate` and `Rotate`. If you want to return something than you've to return `m` - `return m;`

Comment: ok..., now I have way more issues than before! Now i'm really confused. Here is the github repo: https://github.com/bobthetreegod/Game-Engine Please could you look into this. Everything is in math.h and engine.h

Comment: @BobTheTreeGod Nice program. I mad it run. See the last part of the answer to solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you so much!